# str_shuffle() equivalent in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, function, shuffle, phpjs

Like the `str_shuffle()` function in PHP, is there a function similar in shuffling the string in javascript ?

Please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No such function exist, you'll write one yourself. Here's an example:

```
function shuffle(string) {
    var parts = string.split('');
    for (var i = parts.length; i > 0;) {
        var random = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
        var temp = parts[--i];
        parts[i] = parts[random];
        parts[random] = temp;
    }
    return parts.join('');
}

alert(shuffle('abcdef'));
```

Comment: BTW, this is the Fisher–Yates shuffle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 1):

You could use php.js implementation:
http://phpjs.org/functions/str_shuffle:529

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no inbuilt method of String that will randomise the character sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my versinof the php.js function

```
function str_shuffle (str) {

    var newStr = [];

    if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw 'str_shuffle : Parameter str not specified';
    }

    if (typeof str !== 'string') {
        throw 'str_shuffle : Parameter str ( = ' + str + ') is not a string';
    }

    str = str.split (''); 
    while (str.length) {
        newStr.push (str.splice (Math.floor (Math.random () * (str.length - 1)) , 1)[0]);
    }

    return newStr.join ('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it as a prototype:

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var parts = this.split('');

  for (var i = 0, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
    var temp = parts[i];
    parts[i] = parts[j];
    parts[j] = temp;
  }

  return parts.join('');
};
```

Using it like so:

```
var myString = "Hello";
myString = myString.shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend lodash [shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs#shuffle) function.

```
const result = _.shuffle('my_string');
```